# How do I adjust these texts dynamically depending on length of name?

Tags: xetex, r, knitr

The following code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Segoe UI Symbol}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, outer=0cm,     inner=0cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{textblock*}{10cm}(10.6cm,2cm) % {block width} (coords) 
\fontsize{20}{12}\selectfont
`r data2$org_name`  
\end{document}
```

outputs longer strings as

[image]

And this the output for shorter strings

[image]

How do I adjust this slice of code so that long strings and short strings can dynamically align correctly in the same spot? I want them to centered at the same area and be in one line like the example in the first picture.

Comment: Please add a complete code from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` to make it easier to understand your requirement.

Comment: I added those lines for this simple example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED** after several follow-up questions.

When using absolute coordinates, it is necessary to calculate the `y` coordinate from the top edge of the page. (or by adding the intermediate vertical spaces: 8cm = 3cm + 1.5cm + 2cm + 1.5cm)

(1) `\centering` will center the contents in the block.

(2) Use `\textcolor{<color>}{< some text>}` to color the text.

(3) Choose Arial or another sans serif font to have bold face characters: `\setmainfont{Arial}`.

(4) For the underscore in text mode use `\_`.

[image: c]

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex 


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, outer=0cm,     inner=0cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    
{\color{red}    \rule{0.3\textwidth}{3cm}}
\begin{textblock*}{0.5\textwidth}(0.4\textwidth,3cm) % {block width} (coords) 
    \fontsize{20}{12}\selectfont
    \centering  \textcolor{blue}{Highland Park ISD-Dallas County}
\end{textblock*}

\vspace*{2cm}

{\color{red}    \rule{0.3\textwidth}{3cm}}
\begin{textblock*}{0.5\textwidth}(0.4\textwidth,8cm) % {block width} (coords) 
    \fontsize{20}{12}\selectfont
    \centering  \textcolor{blue}{IRA ISD}
\end{textblock*}

\vspace*{2cm}
    
{\color{red}    \rule{0.3\textwidth}{3cm}}
\begin{textblock*}{0.5\textwidth}(0.4\textwidth,13cm) % {block width} (coords) 
     \fontsize{20}{12}\selectfont\centering
     \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{r data 2org\_name}}
\end{textblock*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am going to mark this as the answer. This is exactly what I was looking for but can I ask you an additional question because you seem knowledgeable about font. I want the text to be a dark blue. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @Robert Ramirez Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Can I also apply \textbf such as

\centering \textbf \textcolor{Blue4} {`r data2$org_name`}

Comment: @Robert Ramirez Please see the last updated answwer. (1) Use `\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{r data 2org\_name}}` and (2) Use `\setmainfont{Arial`} or other any font you like with bold characters, instead of `\setmainfont{Segoe UI Symbol} `

Comment: Thank you for all your help! I'll mark the answer.